# No activity with RKObjectManager:loadObjectsAtResourcePath:

Tags: restkit

This is the code I use to load User objects from backend:

```
[RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://localhost:8080"]];
RKObjectMapping *userMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[User class]];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"id"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"userName" toAttribute:@"userName"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"firstName" toAttribute:@"firstName"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"lastName" toAttribute:@"lastName"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"email" toAttribute:@"email"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"facebookId" toAttribute:@"facebookId"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"twitterId" toAttribute:@"twitterId"];


[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setObjectMapping:userMapping forResourcePathPattern:@"/users"];    
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/users" delegate:self];
```

This code runs without problems but there are no requests arriving at the server and no delegate methods are called at the client.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Share manager was not initialised in your code.
Replace first line in your posted code with:

```
[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:[RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://localhost:8080"]]];
```